# ajax call to C# method not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I want to call a method in C# from a client side AJAX/JQuery message.
The client code is:

```
        function TestClickFunc(userId) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Users/UpdateEmailDistributionListFlag",
                type: "POST",
                data: { "userId" :  userId },
                success: function (data) { alert(data); }
            });

        }
```

This method gets called with the correct parameter.
However in my UsersController, this method does not get called;

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult UpdateEmailDistributionListFlag(int userId)
    {
        // db update
        return View();
    }
```

Can you see why?

Comment: Check the HTTP response in Firebug or Fiddler.

Comment: Try making a regular POST call first to determine if the problem is with the AJAX call or the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found was that the CDN was not working;

I can't see the spelling mistake, but it worked when I used my local script!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a route with parameter userId. In the default route the parameter's name is id, not userId so your method will not be found.

Comment: I think my real problem is that I am calling JQuery within a Javascript function, and $ is not being recognised.